# exploding a string to an array separated by capitals

Tags: php, arrays

I will start with an example string

```
LampsHeated MirrorsPower Mirror(s)Intermittent WipersVariable Speed Intermittent WipersPower Driver SeatCloth SeatsBucket SeatsDriver Adjustable LumbarPass-Through Rear SeatRear Bench SeatFloor MatsAdjustable Steering WheelSteering Wheel Audio ControlsTire Pressure MonitorPower Door LocksKeyless EntryRemote Trunk ReleaseSecurity SystemCD ChangerCD PlayerPremium Sound SystemAuxiliary Audio InputA/CRear DefrostAuxiliary Pwr OutletDriver Vanity MirrorPassenger Vanity MirrorDriver Illuminated Vanity MirrorPassenger Illuminated Visor MirrorFront Reading LampsPassenger Air Bag SensorFront Head Air BagRear Head Air BagChild Safety LocksEmergency Trunk Release
```

So as you can see the string has a list of items that are not separated by anything, however they all start with a capital.

So I was looking for a way to convert this string into an array separated by capitals, but also they need to make sure it is not just the second word of the same list, so we check if it has a space before it or not too.

e.g. 'Passenger Vanity MirrorDriver Illuminated Vanity Mirror'

Would become array('Passenger Vanity Mirror','Driver Illuminated Vanity Mirror')

I just dont seem to be able to get my head around how to do it. I am sure a regex, would be good for checking capitals, but dont even know how to do that.
Any ideas of how to tackle this?

Comment: Why are you working with such a terrible data format?

Comment: Is this a predetermined list? Or could each "list" be unique and change from list to list?

Comment: Passenger Vanity Mirror will be split into three if you'll explode using capital letters.

Comment: Its 3rd party data. @Witherwind please re-read the post, it says that we also validate for if there is a space prior.

Comment: You have CD in string

Comment: @user2909486 3rd party data from where? Can't you access a better data format?

Comment: Oh right, ok, open to other suggestions of how I can convert this terrible string into an array.

Comment: @user2909486: Can you update the question to include all the possibilities and how you expect the situation to be handled? Phil's answer probably what you want, but I'm not quite sure if how you want to handle abbreviations like `CD`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$var = preg_split('/(?<=\S)(?=[A-Z])/', 'Passenger Vanity MirrorDriver Illuminated Vanity Mirror');
var_dump($var);
//array(2) {
//  [0] =>
//  string(23) "Passenger Vanity Mirror"
//  [1] =>
//  string(32) "Driver Illuminated Vanity Mirror"
//}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SMtliv4iSu-D8BGq)

But I do not know what to do with abbreviations.

P.S. expression `/(?<=\S)(?<![\-A-Z\/])(?=[A-Z])/` which works with sample data.

Comment: Watch out for *"Power Mirror(s)"*

Comment: Great, that does exactly what I asked. I guess I need to adda extra validation in there for, if it is 'CD' in there. How could we add that as well?

Comment: what issues would the (s) cause? Will it mess up the regex?

Answer (score 2):

Best I could come up with but I doubt it's going to work flawlessly

```
preg_split('/(?<=[^A-Z\s\/-])(?=[A-Z])/', $str)
```

This expression boils down to *"Split on any capital letter immediately preceded by any character that is not a capital letter, space, forward slash or hyphen"*.

You could also use

```
preg_split('/(?<![A-Z\s\/-])(?=[A-Z])/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

which is essentially the same thing only it uses a negative look-behind with positive character class instead of the positive look-behind with negated character class in the first example. The `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` removes an empty first item.

Gives me the following array...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lamps
    [1] => Heated Mirrors
    [2] => Power Mirror(s)
    [3] => Intermittent Wipers
    [4] => Variable Speed Intermittent Wipers
    [5] => Power Driver Seat
    [6] => Cloth Seats
    [7] => Bucket Seats
    [8] => Driver Adjustable Lumbar
    [9] => Pass-Through Rear Seat
    [10] => Rear Bench Seat
    [11] => Floor Mats
    [12] => Adjustable Steering Wheel
    [13] => Steering Wheel Audio Controls
    [14] => Tire Pressure Monitor
    [15] => Power Door Locks
    [16] => Keyless Entry
    [17] => Remote Trunk Release
    [18] => Security System
    [19] => CD Changer
    [20] => CD Player
    [21] => Premium Sound System
    [22] => Auxiliary Audio Input
    [23] => A/CRear Defrost
    [24] => Auxiliary Pwr Outlet
    [25] => Driver Vanity Mirror
    [26] => Passenger Vanity Mirror
    [27] => Driver Illuminated Vanity Mirror
    [28] => Passenger Illuminated Visor Mirror
    [29] => Front Reading Lamps
    [30] => Passenger Air Bag Sensor
    [31] => Front Head Air Bag
    [32] => Rear Head Air Bag
    [33] => Child Safety Locks
    [34] => Emergency Trunk Release
)
```

As you can see, there's an issue around *A/C* and *Rear Defrost*

Comment: Oh wow, so does that mean that if two capital letters are next to each other, then they will be contained together?

Comment: @user2909486 Yes. The pattern requires something else to precede the capital-letter delimiter. I've explained the pattern in my answer